# Insert todays date in worddocument using openxml C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I need to insert in existing word document selfrefreshing todays date using OPENXML.

My code looks like this:

```
public static byte[] InsertHeader(byte[] buffer, string text, string decisionNumber)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
                {
                    var mainPart = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart;
                    var relationshipId = GenerateUniqueRelationshipId(mainPart);
                    var headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>(relationshipId);
                    var relationshipId2 = GenerateUniqueRelationshipId(mainPart);
                    var headerPart2 = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>(relationshipId2);
                    var runProp = new RunProperties();
                    var runProp2 = new RunProperties();
                    var runFont = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Lato" };
                    var runFont2 = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Lato" };
                    var size = new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("20") };
                    var size2 = new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("20") };
                    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
                    var justification2 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Right };
                    paragraphProperties1.Append(justification2);
                    runProp.Append(runFont);
                    runProp.Append(size);
                    runProp2.Append(runFont2);
                    runProp2.Append(size2);
                    var run = new Run(new Text(text));
                    run.PrependChild(runProp);
                    var run2 = new Run(new Text(decisionNumber));
                    run2.PrependChild(runProp2);
                    var header = new Header(new Paragraph(run));
                    header.Save(headerPart);
                    var paragraph2 = new Paragraph();
                    paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties1);
                    paragraph2.Append(run2);
                    var header2 = new Header(paragraph2);
                    header2.Save(headerPart2);
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.SectionProperties sectionProps = mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (sectionProps == null)
                    {
                        sectionProps = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.SectionProperties();
                        mainPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProps);
                    }

                    var headerReference = new HeaderReference() { Id = relationshipId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.First };
                    var headerReference2 = new HeaderReference() { Id = relationshipId2 };
                    sectionProps.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
                    //Adding Title Page property
                    sectionProps.PrependChild(new TitlePage());
                    sectionProps.Append(headerReference);
                    sectionProps.Append(headerReference2);

                    mainPart.Document.Save();
                }
                buffer = stream.ToArray();
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

I need to insert extend "text" variable by inserting in the middle of it todays date.
Similar as you can add in Word using this option:
[image]

Comment: The dialog inserts a Date merge field, not a text variable. There are no text variables in word.

Answer (score 0):

I've created docx using Word with needed DateField then I opened it as zip file and study xml that is inside. Then I worked out resolution that works for me:

```
var mainPart = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart;
                var relationshipId = GenerateUniqueRelationshipId(mainPart);
                var headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>(relationshipId);
                
                var paragraph = new Paragraph(
                        new Run(
                            new RunProperties(
                                new RunFonts()
                                {
                                    Ascii = "Lato",
                                    HighAnsi = "Lato"
                                },
                                new FontSize() { Val = "20" }
                            ),
                            new Text(text1 + " ")
                            {
                                Space = new EnumValue<SpaceProcessingModeValues>(
                                SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve)
                            }),
                        new Run(
                            new RunProperties(
                                new RunFonts()
                                {
                                    Ascii = "Lato",
                                    HighAnsi = "Lato"
                                },
                                new FontSize() { Val = "20" }
                            ),
                            new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Begin },
                            new FieldCode(" DATE Today \\* MERGEFORMAT "),
                            new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Separate },
                            new Run(
                                new Text(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                            ),
                            new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.End }
                        ),
                        new Run(
                            new RunProperties(
                                new RunFonts()
                                {
                                    Ascii = "Lato",
                                    HighAnsi = "Lato"
                                },
                                new FontSize() { Val = "20" }
                            ),
                            new Text(" " + text2)
                            {
                                Space = new EnumValue<SpaceProcessingModeValues>(
                                SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve)
                            })
                );
                var header = new Header(paragraph);
                header.Save(headerPart);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**